# How to refine my jQuery to always work in IE8, currently it is hit and miss

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a webpage that takes in number values from the user and plots them on a grid. Here is an example of the jQuery used when the set of numbers is inputted:

```
$('#c_per,#c_pot').keyup(function() {
        $('.ls_ref').each(function() {
            if($(this).text().search('C') > 0) {
                countDown(this.id);
            }
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace('C', ''));
        });
        if($('#c_per').val() > 0 && $('#c_pot').val() > 0) {
            setGridPosition('C',$('#c_per').val(),$('#c_pot').val());
        }
        var c_per = +$('#c_per').val() || 0;
        var c_pot = +$('#c_pot').val() || 0;
        $('#c_tot').val(c_per + c_pot);
    });
```

c_per and c_pot are the two input:text that the user places numbers in. The category corresponding to each set of numbers can only appear once in the grid, hence the first function within the given keyup event function. The next checks to see that both inputs have a value in them and then calls the setGridPosition function. The rest just adds the total of the two numbers and makes sure the function doesn't crash when there is no value in one of the two inputs.

```
function setGridPosition(cat,per,pot) {
    var id = "ls_" + per + "_" + pot;
    $('#'+id).append(cat);
    var check = per + "-" + pot;
    switch(check) {
        case '1-1': case '2-1': case '1-2': case '2-2':
            counts.q_1 += 1;
            switch(check) {
                case '1-1':
                    priority_one_count.s_1_1++; break;
                case '2-1':
                    priority_one_count.s_2_1++; break;
                case '1-2':
                    priority_one_count.s_1_2++; break;
                case '2-2':
                    priority_one_count.s_2_2++; break;
            }    
            break;
        case '3-1': case '4-1': case '5-1': case '3-2': case '4-2': case '5-2':
            counts.q_2 += 1;
            switch(check) {
                case '3-1':
                    priority_two_count.s_3_1++; break;
                case '4-1':
                    priority_two_count.s_4_1++; break;
                case '5-1':
                    priority_two_count.s_5_1++; break;
                case '3-2':
                    priority_two_count.s_3_2++; break;
                case '4-2':
                    priority_two_count.s_4_2++; break;
                case '5-2':
                    priority_two_count.s_5_2++; break;
            }
            break;
        case '3-3': case '4-3': case '3-4':
            counts.q_3 += 1;
            switch(check) {
                case '3-3':
                    priority_three_count.s_3_3++; break;
                case '4-3':
                    priority_three_count.s_4_3++; break;
                case '3-4':
                    priority_three_count.s_3_4++; break;
            }
            break;
        case '5-3': case '4-4': case '3-5':
            counts.q_4 += 1; break;
        case '5-4': case '4-5': case '5-5':
            counts.q_5 += 1; break;
        default: counts.q_6 += 1;
    }
}
```

Most of this function is just keeping track of what is where for some stats I need to compile. Not sure if the falling-through switch statements are effecting IE8.

I tried to get jsfiddle.net to work with this site, but I can't figure it out. I have a temporary site setup where you can check out the full version. **-link removed-**

This code works every time with Chrome and FireFox and works about 95% of the time with IE8 (required support). Normally 9/11 sets of numbers generates the position on the grid correctly.

Is there something in this code that IE8 has trouble with?

Comment: What is the countDown function doing?

Comment: It is only counting down a variable. So basically, variable--;

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you post the code?

Comment: All it does is decrement a variable. It does not do anything else. There is no effect from that function that could possibly stop something else from working.

Comment: A fiddle of your example would give you a quicker answer, viewing the source of a link to a website with the code running on it isn't very helpful because we can't just manipulate it to determine what the issue is.

Comment: As I said in the question, I couldn't get the fiddle to work properly.

Comment: Just curious, what's the `+$` in the lines `var c_per = +$('#c_per').val() || 0;` `var c_pot = +$('#c_pot').val() || 0;` ? I've never seen that before.

Comment: It is a shorthand way of keeping that variable a number data type. Could be written as var c_per = parseInt($('#c_per').val()) || 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that IE8's javascript engine would inconsistently handle $('#id').val() data types. I parsed each value to Int before handling them and this seems to fix the error.

Thanks for everyone taking a look at this. Sorry I couldn't get fiddle to run it properly.

Answer (score 1):

a wild guess, but don't you need as well a break; for the last default: statement? Is like within a set of switches and perhaps that is making it to jump to another case pretty much like the way you do with    case 'whatever' : case 'yeah' : can you try add the break for the default statement? I looks like a very complicated algorithm, but hopefully that's the issue.

Comment: I will give that a try, but it will have to wait til tomorrow. I will let you know if that fixes it, although I am not holding my breath. Thanks. :)

Comment: I added the breaks to each default in the switches. It did not fix the problem. Thanks for the idea though. Was a good thing to check.

Comment: Then I guess that you need to accept your own answer as you have solved it @ahhchuu, glad that you have sorted it out :)

Comment: "You can only accept your answer tomorrow" :P I would if I could. lol If you want to write it up I can accept it and get this into answered state.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to simplify the switch statements?

```
    function setGridPosition(cat,per,pot) {
        var id = "ls_" + per + "_" + pot;
        $('#'+id).append(cat);
        var check = per + "-" + pot;
        switch(check) {
          case '1-1':   counts.q_1 += 1;  priority_one_count.s_1_1++; break;
          case '2-1':  counts.q_1 += 1;  priority_one_count.s_2_1++;  break;
          case '1-2':  counts.q_1 += 1;  priority_one_count.s_1_2++; break;
          case '2-2':  counts.q_1 += 1;  priority_one_count.s_2_2++;  break;


          case '3-1': counts.q_2 += 1; priority_two_count.s_3_1++; break;
          case '4-1': counts.q_2 += 1;   priority_two_count.s_4_1++; break;
          case '5-1': counts.q_2 += 1;  priority_two_count.s_5_1++; break;
          case '3-2': counts.q_2 += 1;  priority_two_count.s_3_2++; break;
          case '4-2':  counts.q_2 += 1;  priority_two_count.s_4_2++; break;
          case '5-2': counts.q_2 += 1; priority_two_count.s_5_2++; break;


          case '3-3': counts.q_3 += 1;  priority_three_count.s_3_3++; break;
          case '4-3': counts.q_3 += 1;  priority_three_count.s_4_3++; break;
          case '3-4':counts.q_3 += 1;  priority_three_count.s_3_4++; break;



           case '5-3':  counts.q_4 += 1; break;
           case '4-4':  counts.q_4 += 1; break;
           case '3-5':  counts.q_4 += 1; break;


           case '5-4':  counts.q_5 += 1; break;
           case '4-5':  counts.q_5 += 1; break;
            case '5-5':  counts.q_5 += 1; break;

            default: counts.q_6 += 1; break;
        }
    }
```

Is hard without knowing when this function is called and what is really being used for.. hope that leads you to find the issue with IE 8 :)

Comment: Turns out it was IE8 mishandling data types. I will take your advice on this though. Those switches should be simplified. Writing it your way makes me realize how inconsistent I was with incrementing. :P